# Copy content of C variable into a register (GCC)

Tags: c, linux, gcc, assembly, x86

Since I'm very new to GCC, I'm facing a problem in inline assembly code. The problem is that I'm not able to figure out how to copy the contents of a C variable (which is of type `UINT32`) into the register `eax`. I have tried the below code:

```
__asm__
(
    // If the LSB of src is a 0, use ~src.  Otherwise, use src.
    "mov     $src1, %eax;"
    "and     $1,%eax;"
    "dec     %eax;"
    "xor     $src2,%eax;"

    // Find the number of zeros before the most significant one.
    "mov     $0x3F,%ecx;"
    "bsr     %eax, %eax;"
    "cmove   %ecx, %eax;"
    "xor     $0x1F,%eax;"
);
```

However `mov $src1, %eax;` doesn't work.

Could someone suggest a solution to this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I guess what you are looking for is [extended assembly](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#s5) e.g.:

```
    int a=10, b;
    asm ("movl %1, %%eax;   /* eax = a */
          movl %%eax, %0;" /* b = eax */
         :"=r"(b)         /* output */
         :"r"(a)         /* input */
         :"%eax"        /* clobbered register */
         );
```

In the example above, we made the value of `b` equal to that of `a` using assembly instructions and `eax` register:

```
int a = 10, b;
b = a;
```

Please see the inline comments.

**note:**

```
mov $4, %eax          // AT&T notation

mov eax, 4            // Intel notation
```

A good read about [inline assembly](https://github.com/0xAX/linux-insides/blob/master/Theory/asm.md) in GCC environment.

Comment: So does that mean that u copied the contents of eax to b is it??

Comment: This example shows you both how to copy from and to a register by having a c variable...

Comment: Can you pls specify which line it is copying to a register?? Coz that is my main requirement...

Comment: I have taken care of the source and destination. My question is copying contents of the variable src1 to register eax as given in the above code. So pls describe how to do the same.

Comment: In general you should really be using constraints to instruct the compiler to put operands into particular registers if necessary. For `eax` you can use `"a"`.