# inline asm with sideeffects

Tags: c, assembly, arm, clang, inline-assembly

I want to use inline asm for ARMv7 with clang 3.4, in order to write low level code that accesses the CPUs control registers.  As a test, I wrote a program that reads from a register, conditionally fiddles with some bits, and writes back the new value.

However, when I look at the produced machine code the entire bit-fiddling has been optimized away.  Apparently I have not used the right asm constraints to tell clang that the result of writing to the register depends on what is being written. (I only used a simple "volatile" modifier).

How should I write the inline asm code so that clang generates correct asm?  Here is the code `test.c`

```
typedef unsigned int uint32_t;

// code that reads and writes the ID_PFR1 register

uint32_t read_ID_PFR1() {
  uint32_t a;
  asm volatile ("mrc     p15, 0, %0, c0, c1, 1" : : "r"(a) : );
  return a;
}

void write_ID_PFR1(uint32_t a) {
  asm volatile ("mcr     p15, 0, %0, c0, c1, 1" :"=r"(a) :  :  );
}

// regular c code that modifies the register

uint32_t foo(uint32_t b) {
  uint32_t a;
  a = read_ID_PFR1();
  write_ID_PFR1(b);
  return a+b;
}

void bit_fiddle() {
  uint32_t a;
  a = read_ID_PFR1();
  if ((a & 0x3) == 1) {
    a |= 1<<2;
  }
  a |= 1<<3;
  write_ID_PFR1(a);
}
```

I compiled it with

```
clang-3.4 -target armv7a-none-eabi test.c -o test -O3
```

This is the resulting machine code

```
$ arm-linux-gnueabi-objdump -S test

test:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <read_ID_PFR1>:
   0:   ee100f31    mrc 15, 0, r0, cr0, cr1, {1}
   4:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00000008 <write_ID_PFR1>:
   8:   ee000f31    mcr 15, 0, r0, cr0, cr1, {1}
   c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00000010 <foo>:
  10:   ee100f31    mrc 15, 0, r0, cr0, cr1, {1}
  14:   ee000f31    mcr 15, 0, r0, cr0, cr1, {1}
  18:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

0000001c <bit_fiddle>:
  1c:   ee100f31    mrc 15, 0, r0, cr0, cr1, {1}
  20:   ee000f31    mcr 15, 0, r0, cr0, cr1, {1}
  24:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

As you can see in `<bit_fiddle>`, nothing is left between the `mrc` and `mcr` instructions.  And also see how `foo` fails to add together `a+b` in the produced machine code.

Comment: try compiling with `clang-3.4 -target armv7a-none-eabi test.c -o test -O0`

Comment: Did I just mix up the "r" and "=r" constraints?  Should it be the other way around?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are close. The `"="` means that the operand is write-only:

> While using constraints, for more precise control over the effects of
>   constraints, GCC provides us with constraint modifiers. Mostly used
>   constraint modifiers are
>
> "=" : Means that this operand is write-only for this instruction; the
>   previous value is discarded and replaced by output data. "&" : Means
>   that this operand is an earlyclobber operand, which is modified before
>   the instruction is finished using the input operands. Therefore, this
>   operand may not lie in a register that is used as an input operand or
>   as part of any memory address. An input operand can be tied to an
>   earlyclobber operand if its only use as an input occurs before the
>   early result is written.

The input and output is determined by the order in the list separated with `:`

```
  asm ( assembler template 
       : output operands                  /* optional */
       : input operands                   /* optional */
       : list of clobbered registers      /* optional */
       );
```

1. read [gcc inline assembly HOWTO](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html).
2. [Copy content of C variable into a register (GCC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494818/copy-content-of-c-variable-into-a-register-gcc/14494864#14494864)

Answer (score 5):

I'm was using the "r" and "=r" constraints in the wrong way.  `write` should have an input constraint, and `read` should have an output constraint.

This is the way to do it:

```
uint32_t read_ID_PFR1() {
  uint32_t a;
  asm volatile ("mrc     p15, 0, %0, c0, c1, 1" : "=r"(a) : : );
  return a;
}

void write_ID_PFR1(uint32_t a) {
  asm volatile ("mcr     p15, 0, %0, c0, c1, 1" : : "r"(a) :  );
}
```

Here is the code produced for `bit_fiddle`:

```
00000020 <bit_fiddle>:
  20:   ee100f31    mrc 15, 0, r0, cr0, cr1, {1}
  24:   e2001003    and r1, r0, #3
  28:   e3510001    cmp r1, #1
  2c:   03800004    orreq   r0, r0, #4
  30:   e3800008    orr r0, r0, #8
  34:   ee000f31    mcr 15, 0, r0, cr0, cr1, {1}
  38:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

Pretty nice...